# PHP / htaccess: block indexation when GET parameter is present

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to prevent search engines from indexing with some specific get parameters.

Example:

- `https://www.example.com/mypage.php` should be indexed
- `https://www.example.com/mypage.php?myparam=1` should not be indexed

I have many pages (more than 10k) with get parameters that are indexed on top of the main page despite sending a no index in the header.

I have this in robots.txt:

```
Disallow: /*?*myparam=
```

And this in the html:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

All pages also have a canonical referring to the main page (without get params)

I would like to try the following but as it may have catastrophic consequences if I doing it wrongly, I'd like to check if my approach is ok:

```
<FilesMatch "\.php">
   <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /myparam/">
       Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive"
   </If>
</Files>
```

Is this approach ok? Or do you see a better one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this in robots.txt:
>
> ```
> Disallow: /*?*myparam=
> ```

That's the problem.

`robots.txt` prevents search engine bots from *crawling* your site. This does not necessarily prevent these pages from getting *indexed* if these pages are being linked to.

If you prevent *crawling* then search engine bots are not going to see the meta robots tag in the HTML or `X-Robots-Tag` HTTP response header, because the page is never requested.

(Although you would normally be notified of this in the search results with a search description along the lines of "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt - learn more".)

So, you should remove the entry in the `robots.txt` file.

However, there's also the matter of *how* you are determining the pages are indexed and whether this is really a concern. For example, if you are using a `site:` search then this often returns URLs that are not ordinarily returned in organic searches. It is unusual for a URL that is blocked in `robots.txt` to be returned in the organic search results since the "content" of that page is not indexed - just the URL. Often, a `site:` search is the only way to dig out these URL-only "indexed" URLs.

> All pages also have a canonical referring to the main page (without get params)

This should be enough by itself and is the preferred option if the non-parameter version of the URL is genuinely the canonical version (ie. not a completely different page).

The "canonical" tag (if honoured) will effectively pass link-juice to the canonical URL.

However, the canonical tag is only "advisory". If Google determines that the canonical URL is not really canonical (eg. if it is sufficiently different) then it is ignored.

You can also resolve URL parameter canonicalisation in GSC.

> ```
> <FilesMatch "\.php">
>    <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /myparam/">
>        Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive"
>    </If>
> </Files>
> ```

UPDATE: The closing "tag" should be `</FilesMatch>`, not `</Files>`. Or, use the non-regex `<Files ".php">` directive instead (preferable).

Otherwise, this is "OK", except that it does potentially catch too much. It would set the `X-Robots-Tag` header on any request that maps to a file that *contains* `.php` - not just a file extension (even if the requested URL itself is not for a `.php` file) and that request contains the string `myparam` anywhere in the query string (which is a bit general, since it would also match `abcmyparamxyz=1` - if that is a possibility).

You could be more specific and avoid the `<FilesMatch>` directive. For example:

```
 <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == '/mypage.php' && %{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(^|&)myparam=/">
     Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive"
 </If>
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the non specific approach first and it resulted in a error 500 on all pages :( 
I understand the need to remove the line from robots.txt but my issue is that there are so many pages that should not be indexed that it affects my crawl budget. When Google finally stop crawling those pages, I see my performance increasing.

Comment: @Laurent Ah, you are incorrectly using `</Files>` to close the container - it should be `</FilesMatch>`. However, using the simpler (non-regex) `<Files>` container would be preferable here. If Google's crawling is effecting performance then it sounds like you have no option to block crawling with `robots.txt`. But, how are you discovering these indexed pages and are these pages actually being returned in organic search results? If the pages are blocked with `robots.txt` then it is rare for these URLs to be returned since the "content" is not indexed. I've updated my answer.

Comment: ah my bad, I didn't pay attention to the closing tag. I can see the pages showing up when searching in Google. It's a mistake I did last year by calling comments in the page with this extra param and Google has indexed all comments separately and I ended up with 10k pages instead of 1k. Robots.txt did not help, the noindex meta in html didn't completely solve the problem either. That's why I'm now trying with htaccess.